# django rest framework: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when calling get method of related table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building an django rest api for saving/managing customer data for my project. I have two models. Customer for storing basic customer details and CustomerDetails for storing a bunch of customer details. I want to write a single api to create/update data for both the models.

Now my code is saving the user data. But I now I can't get the customer data. When I call the get method, the following error occurs.

```
TypeError at /api/v1/customer
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/customer
```

Also, Do I need to do anything extra to use this code for updation (PUT)

urls.py

```
router.register(r'customer', views.CustomerViewSet, 'customers')
```

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    """some more fields to go"""


# Create your models here.
class CustomerDetails(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,    primary_key=True, )

    spouse_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    """many more fields to go"""
```

serializers.py

```
class CustomerDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerDetails
        fields = ('spouse_name',)


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer_details = CustomerDetailsSerializer( required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('name', 'city', 'customer_details', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        user = request.user
        # create user
        customer = Customer.objects.create(
            user = user,
            name = validated_data['name'],
            city = validated_data['city'],
            # etc ...
        )
        print(json.dumps(validated_data, indent=4))
        customer_details_data = validated_data.pop('customer_details')
        # create profile
        customer_details = CustomerDetails.objects.create(
            customer = customer,
            spouse_name = customer_details_data['spouse_name'],

        )
        customer.customer_details = customer_details_data;
        return customer


class CustomerListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Customer
    customer_details = CustomerDetailsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    customer_photo_thumb = Customer.get_thumbnail_url
    customer_details = ''
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrieve':
            return CustomerListSerializer
        return CustomerListSerializer
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace

Comment: complete stacktrace:  http://pastebin.com/K17QmM91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `.get_queryset` return `None` replace like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Customer.objects.all()
```

In fact your `get_queryset` method is not necessary since the queryset attribute does not change.

Comment: it worked. Thanks. Now it returns only the customer details. Is there any way to return the customer details too along with that results?